# Command Error: /usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.6': No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, wicked-pdf

I ran into a problem on our production server, we have a Rails app that generates a PDF using the gem `wicked_pdf` and it's throwing the following error:

```
Failed to execute:
["/var/www/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20201004-5058-g9f64a.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20201004-5058-1gjfrw5.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.6': No such file or directory
```

Now the weird thing is that this works fine from a rake task (the rake task is executed with `sudo`)

and of course ruby is resolving fine:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ which ruby2.6
/usr/bin/ruby2.6

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ echo $PATH
/home/julien/bin:/home/julien/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

The Rails app runs with the `www-data` user.
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

My guess is whatever bash the app is using to execute the binary is missing something in its `$PATH` or maybe I need a symbolic link somewhere but i have no clue, any ideas?

How can i debug this to understand where the problem is?
How can i check and maybe modify what shell PATH is loaded by Rails?

**UPDATE**

The Rails app runs with Nginx + Passenger.

`ENV['PATH']` outputs the following:

```
/var/www/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/bin
```

Here's the relevant part of the code that generates the PDF:

```
#generate the PDF
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
      template: 'templates/_doc',
      locals: {
        url: self.url,
        signature: sig,
        name: full_name,
        title: "some title"
      }
    )
  )

  #save the file
  save_path = Rails.root.join(PATH_TO_STORE_FILE, "some-filename-#{self.clean_url}.pdf")
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
  end
```

Comment: This is a likely PATH problem. Www-data is not the same as your own user account, and therefore PATH is not set up the same. Under what system are you running Rails? Apache Passenger? There's many ways to set PATH to get around this problem, but it's hard to give a direct answer without knowing all the specifics.

Comment: I suggest to output `ENV['PATH']` on one of your Rails pages, for initial debugging.

Comment: Also what does the code look like that calls `wkhtmltopdf`. Please include this code in the post.

Comment: @Casper i've added the requested information, i'm quite surprised about how little there is in that `EN['PATH']`, no wonder it can't find ruby, how can i update that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of figuring out where to edit `PATH`, the easiest way to fix your problem is:

```
cd /var/www/myapp/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.6 .
```

This way you will have a link pointing to `ruby2.6` in your vendor bin folder, and since that folder is in the path of your web server, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

WickedPdf attempts to figure out where `wkhtmltopdf` is by calling `which wkhtmltopdf` in some cases. Here it is picking up a binary stub (binstub) that invokes Ruby 2.6, but the process invoking it doesn't have that in their PATH.

You can explicitly specify a path to your `wkhtmltopdf` binary like so:

```rb
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

Ideally this should be direct path to the actual binary, and not a binstub, however some gems that provide `wkhtmltopdf` as a binary, use the binstub to switch binaries based on the platform executing it.

If using one of those, something like this should work:

```rb
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64"
}
```